# Vertical centering text in frametitle in beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, frame-title

I have a picture and text in my `\frametitle` in Beamer. I put them next to each other through `\tabular`.
Now I'm wondering how can I vertically center the text and the image relative to the blue background of that part of the slide? I'm also open to not use `\tabular` if it's easier to center using something else.

The picture how it looks now is shown below
[image: picture1]

The minimal working example with the test image is given below:

```tex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\graphicspath{ {./images169/} }

\title[My title]
{My title\\[2ex]
project\\2021/2022.}

\author[D. Stokić]
{Dušan Stokić}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{
 \begin{tabular}[t]{l c}
  \includegraphics[width=.175\textwidth]{p4-logo} & frame title\\
 \end{tabular}
 }
 \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{section1}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{
 \begin{tabular}[t]{l c}
  \includegraphics[width=.175\textwidth]{p4-logo} & frame title\\
 \end{tabular}
 }
 \begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{p4-logo}
 \end{figure}
 \begin{block}{basic:}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item <1-> item1,
   \item <2-> \textcolor{red}{item2}
  \end{itemize}
 \end{block}
\end{frame}

\section{section2}

\begin{frame}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: p4-logo]

Comment: Do you want to include the same image on all slides?

Comment: @leandriis I have one slides at the end where I don't use it but other than that, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\graphicspath{ {./images169/} }

\title[My title]
{My title\\[2ex]
project\\2021/2022.}

\author[D. Stokić]
{Dušan Stokić}

\date{\today}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{%
    \begin{tblr}{Q[c]X[l]}
        \raisebox{-.26\height}{\includegraphics[width=.175\textwidth]{p4-logo}} & #1\\
    \end{tblr}}   
    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{\mytitle{First frame title}}
 \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{section1}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{\mytitle{Second frame title}}
 \begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{p4-logo}
 \end{figure}
 \begin{block}{basic:}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item <1-> item1,
   \item <2-> \textcolor{red}{item2}
  \end{itemize}
 \end{block}
\end{frame}

\section{section2}

\begin{frame}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]